# Kubernetes POD delete with Pattern Match or Wildcard

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

When I am using below it deletes the running POD after matching the pattern from commandline:

```
kubectl get pods -n bi-dev --no-headers=true | awk '/group-react/{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete -n bi-dev pod
```

However when I am using this command as an alias in .bash_profile it doesn't execute . 
This is how I defined it :

```
 alias kdpgroup="kubectl get pods -n bi-dev --no-headers=true | awk '/group-react/{print $1}'|  kubectl delete -n bi-dev pod"
```

when execute this as below I get below error in commandline:

```
~ $ kdpgroup
error: resource(s) were provided, but no name, label selector, or --all flag specified
```

When I define this in .bash_profile I get this :

```
~ $ . ./.bash_profile
-bash: alias: }| xargs  kubectl delete -n bi-dev pod: not found
~ $
```

Am I missing something to delete POD using Pattern Match or with Wilcard  ?

thanks

Answer (score 89, accepted):

> Am I missing something to delete POD using Pattern Match or with Wilcard?

When using Kubernetes it is more common to use *labels* and *selectors*. E.g. if you deployed an application, you usually set a label on the pods e.g. `app=my-app` and you can then get the pods with e.g. `kubectl get pods -l app=my-app`.

Using this aproach, it is easier to delete the pods you are interested in, with e.g.

```
kubectl delete pods -l app=my-app
```

or with namespaces

```
kubectl delete pods -l app=my-app -n default
```

See more on [Kubernetes Labels and Selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/)

**Set-based selector**

> I have some pod's running in the name of "superset-react" and "superset-graphql" and I want to search my wildcard superset and delete both of them in one command

I suggest that those pods has labels `app=something-react` and `app=something-graphql`. If you want to classify those apps, e.g. if your "superset" varies, you could add a label `app-type=react` and `app-type=graphql` to all those type of apps.

Then you can delete pods for both app types with this command:

```
kubectl delete pods -l 'app-type in (react, graphql)'
```

Comment: that doesn't answer my question though ... I have some pod's running in the name of "superset-react" and "superset-graphql" and I want to search my wildcard superset and delete both of them in one command and put that command into .bash_profile so that I don't need to type everytime . How can I achieve this ? your answer doesn't address that .

Comment: yes, I answered on how this usually is done when working with Kubernetes. I have updated my answer with how you delete both apps with a single command.

Comment: thanks and it works ... I realize I have to do something like this : kubectl delete pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=middleware   because I have no names specified . So referring here if somebody has same issue

Comment: This is the k8s style answer.

Answer (score 60):

As the question asks, this is about using a wild card. Let me give examples on using wild cards to delete pods.

**Delete Pods which contain the word "application"**

Replace `<namespace>` with the namespace you want to delete pods from.

```
kubectl get pods -n <namespace> --no-headers=true | awk '/application/{print $1}'| xargs  kubectl delete -n <namespace> pod
```

This will give a response like the following. It will print out the deleted pods.

```
pod "sre-application-7fb4f5bff9-8crgx" deleted
pod "sre-application-7fb4f5bff9-ftzfd" deleted
pod "sre-application-7fb4f5bff9-rrkt2" deleted
```

**Delete Pods which contain "application" or "service"**

Replace `<namespace>` with the namespace you want to delete pods from.

```
kubectl get pods -n <namespace> --no-headers=true | awk '/application|service/{print $1}'| xargs  kubectl delete -n <namespace> pod
```

This will give a response like the following. It will print out the deleted pods.

```
pod "sre-application-7fb4f5bff9-8crgx" deleted
pod "sre-application-7fb4f5bff9-ftzfd" deleted
pod "sre-service-7fb4f5bff9-rrkt2" deleted
```

Comment: `kubectl get pods -n <namespace> --no-headers=true | awk '/application/{print $1}'| xargs  kubectl delete -n <namespace> pod` is an absolute lifesaver :)))

Comment: this answers worked well for me

Comment: amazing, this is the right answer

Comment: wonderful! love it <3

Answer (score 5):

You just need to escape the '$1' variable in the awk command:

```
alias kdpgroup="kubectl get pods -n bi-dev --no-headers=true | awk '/group-react/{print \$1}'| xargs kubectl delete -n bi-dev pod"
```

I know that escape is boring, and if you want to avoid it you can use as a function in you .bash_profile:

```
kdpgroup() {
    kubectl get pods -n default --no-headers=true | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod -n default
}
```

Comment: I get error while running this alias in commandline or through .bash_profile : kdpgroup
error: resource(s) were provided, but no name, label selector, or --all flag specified . Also while set into .bash_profile and ended up with below error : . ./.bash_profile
-bash: ./.bash_profile: line 33: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: ./.bash_profile: line 33: `kdpgroup() {'

Comment: @pauldx, I'm sorry, I forgot to include `xargs` on the alias command. I've updated the command, could try again and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: apologize delay reply . Yes this perfectly works . thanks

Answer (score 3):

A robust way with variables, based on @keetSugathadasa answer:

```
ns="optional-namespace"
regex="pattern"

kubectl get pods ${ns:+ -n $ns} --no-headers | awk /${regex}/'{print $1}' \ 
| xargs kubectl delete ${ns:+ -n $ns} pod
```

Answer (score 2):

using grep you can filter the keyword like this and delete matching pod name like this

```
kubectl get pods   --no-headers=true | awk '{print $1}' | grep keyword |  xargs kubectl delete pod
```